# How do I put Icons in the y Axis for a Dynamic Highcharts chart?

Tags: dynamic, highcharts, icons

Does anyone have an example for Dynamic Highcharts where the y axis uses icons (smiley/frowney faces for example) instead of alphanumeric characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set useHTML true in formatter function of yAxis label.See the code below and [working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/za7n3h29/13/)

for dynamic image, you can put image path as variable. If you don't want to show axis value remove "this.value" from formatter function

```
yAxis: { labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            return '<img src="http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png" alt="" style="vertical-align: middle; width: 32px; height: 32px"/>'+ this.value;
        },
        useHTML: true
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else is looking for making a chart with y axis having multiple images, here's how I did it:

```
        var chartScales =  scales.map(function(x){ return { value:x.Text, key:++imageIndex, image:x.DefaultImage }; });

        var chart = $("#chartContainer").highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'spline'
            },
            yAxis:{
                categories: chartScales,
                labels: {
                    formatter : function()
                    {
                        // if there's an image use it, otherwise use the text, or key value
                        if(this.value.image != null)
                            return "<img src='"+ this.value.image +"'  style='vertical-align: middle; width: 32px; height: 32px'/>"+(this.value.value != null ? this.value.value : this.value.key);
                        return this.value.value != null ? this.value.value : this.value.key;
                    },
                    useHTML: true
                }
            },
            series: [{
                data: []
            }]
        });
```