# How to put highcharts symbols on xAxis formatter?

Tags: highcharts

I currently was looking at [How do I put Icons in the y Axis for a Dynamic Highcharts chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33743330/how-do-i-put-icons-in-the-y-axis-for-a-dynamic-highcharts-chart)

My question is similar but here, I want to return a triangle symbol without an image.
I want the axis to have a triangular symbol on a specific point

image of what i am trying to establish
[image]

i have a formatter

```
chartOptions.Xaxis.labels.formatter = function() {
   if (<some point>) {
      return <triangle symbol>
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new dummy series to render this point:

```
  {
    marker: {
        symbol: 'triangle'
    },
    enableMouseTracking: false,
    color: 'red',
    data: [{
      x: 3,
      y: 0,
    }]
  }
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rqyujk38/

Comment: but, just wondering that since the highlighted point is in Xaxis, shouldn't it be as part of xAxis formatting? it there any way to use the same marker symbol 'triangle' in the formatter.

Comment: although the point is a triangle symbol, I see that legend still shows a circular point. let me know how to fix that legend symbol

Comment: change the series type to 'scatter' should do the job: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wta3s2gq/

Comment: yup, that seems to work. will try that. thanks, Sebastian.